# How to do always necessary pre processing / cleaning with intake?

Tags: intake

I'm having a use case where:

- I always need to apply a pre-processing step to the data before being able to use it. (Because the naming etc. don't follow community conventions enforced by some software further down the processing chain.)
- I cannot change the raw data. (Because it might be in a repo I don't control, or because it's too big to duplicate, ...)

If I aim at providing a user with the easiest and most transparent way of obtaining the data in a pre-processed way, I can see two ways of doing this:

### 1. Load unprocessed data with intake and apply the pre-processing immediately:

```py
import intake
from my_tools import pre_process

cat = intake.open_catalog('...')
raw_df = cat.some_data.read()
df = pre_process(raw_df)
```

### 2. Apply the pre-processing step with the `.read()` call.

Catalog:

```yaml
sources:
  some_data:
    args:
      urlpath: "/path/to/some_raw_data.csv"
    description: "Some data (already preprocessed)"
    driver: csv
    preprocess: my_tools.pre_process
```

And:

```py
import intake

cat = intake.open_catalog('...')
df = cat.some_data.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 2. is not possible in Intake right now; Intake was designed to be "load" rather than "process", so we've avoided the pipeline idea for now, but we might come back to it in the future.

However, you have a couple of options within Intake that you could consider alongside Option 1., above:

- make your own driver, which implements the load and any processing exactly how you like. Writing drivers is pretty easy, and can involve arbitrary code/complexity
- write an *alias*-type driver, which takes the output of an entry in the same catalog and does something to it. See the [docs](https://intake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_base.html#intake.source.base.AliasSource) and [code](https://github.com/intake/intake/blob/master/intake/source/base.py#L388) for pointers.